# How do i get the total number of comments from this JSON array using php?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im tring to show a list of articles on my site with a authour, date and **comments** field below the article so that users can see the number of comments for an article before even opening it.

The coments are from facebook and im using the graph api which returns the following JSON code per article, how do i get the total number of comments from this? Thanks

I have tried json_decode but the arrays am getting are all with count zero.

```
{
   "http://www.withinzambia.com/technology-and-it/your-modem-isnt-that-fast.html": {
      "comments": {
         "data": [
            {
               "id": "10151004341202332_23086817",
               "from": {
                  "name": "Cindi Mutale",
                  "id": "1045450015732187"
               },
               "message": "Glad someone finally pointed this out.",
               "can_remove": false,
               "created_time": "2012-07-02T19:46:58+0000",
               "like_count": 0,
               "user_likes": false
            },
            {
               "id": "10151002332_23094740",
               "from": {
                  "name": "Chanda Mike",
                  "id": "1000034452054679"
               },
               "message": "my modem is 7mbps, so that's not 7MB per second?",
               "can_remove": false,
               "created_time": "2012-07-03T13:51:24+0000",
               "like_count": 0,
               "user_likes": false
            },
            {
               "id": "10151004341202332_23094782",
               "from": {
                  "name": "Precious Chulu",
                  "id": "100242343243281187"
               },
               "message": "The max for the modem in the picture is 7mbps, which is actually about 900kb when you divide by 8, so you will never download at more than 1mb per second with these modems even when MTN or Airtel upgrades the network.",
               "can_remove": false,
               "created_time": "2012-07-03T13:57:56+0000",
               "like_count": 0,
               "user_likes": false
            }
         ],
         "paging": {
            "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/10151004341202332/comments?value=1&redirect=1&limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=10151004341202332_23094782"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  ...
  $count = 0;
  $array = json_decode($input, true);
  foreach($array AS $website) {
    $count += count($website['comments']['data']);
  }
  ...
?>
```

$count is answer.

[Bonus :)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Thanks alot! You ve really saved alot of time! I ve been trying to do this since yesterday. Wonder why Facebook doesnt post that on their site.

Comment: It's usually considered proper to tick the green arrow for solutions people gave that answer your question. Glad it's working. :D

Comment: Sorry i thought i needed to increase my reputation points first, coz i tried the up arrow and it failed coz i ve few rep points since am new here. I was actually browsing questions so that when i get some points, i can come back here to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$jsonArr = ' ..your JSON array.. ';

$decodedArr = json_decode($jsonArr);

$num_comments = count($decodedArr->{'http://www.withinzambia.com/technology-and-it/your-modem-isnt-that-fast.html'}->comments->data);

echo $num_comments;
```

tested and works.
be aware that if you load your JSON into a string, like i did here, single quotes will need to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks! Never knew you can do that